# Python object typecasting and XML

Tags: python, xml, object, casting

I'm coming from Java, C++ and Delphi, now I'm working on a small project in Python. So far I could most problems solve but I have following unsolved:

I just want to substitute/overwrite a method getAttribute() of a XML Node by type casting the xml node into ext_xml_node, so that every function of the fore mentioned project uses the new getAttribute. As far as I could read there is no way to real type cast (Like C++ etc.) in python, so I came on the idea to make at certain functions (which calls other sub functions like a dispatcher with a xml node argument) a type cast of the argument to the new class ext_xml_node

```
class ext_xml_node(xml_node):
...
   def getAttribute(self, name):
      unhandled_value = super...(name)
      handled_value= dosomethingiwth(unhandled_value)
      return handled_value

def dispatcher(self, xml_node):
        for child_node in xml_node.childNodes:
            if child_node.nodeName == 'setvariable':
                bla = ext_xml_node(child_node)
                self.handle_setvariable_statement(bla)

def handle_setvariable_statement(xml_node):
   varname= xml_node.getAttribute("varname") 
   # Now it should call ext_xml_node.getAttribute Method
```

I don't want to substitute each getAttribute function in this project, and is there another way (duck typing surely isn't working) or should I really write a function with that yield over each attribute - and how?

Comment: It isn't entirely clear what you are asking for. Can you produce a short, complete, stand-alone program that demonstrates your question? See [mcve] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

lxml provides custom element classes which should suit your needs.

```
xml = '''\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://example.com">
  <element1>
    <element2/>
  </element1>
</root>'''

from lxml import etree

class MyXmlClass1(etree.ElementBase):
   def getAttribute(self):
      print '1'

class MyXmlClass2(etree.ElementBase):
   def getAttribute(self):
      print '2'

nsprefix = '{http://example.com}'

fallback = etree.ElementDefaultClassLookup(element = MyXmlClass1)
lookup = etree.ElementNamespaceClassLookup(fallback)
parser = etree.XMLParser()
parser.set_element_class_lookup(lookup)
namespace = lookup.get_namespace('http://example.com')

namespace['element2'] = MyXmlClass2

root = etree.XML(xml, parser)

root.getAttribute()
>>> 1
element1 = root.getchildren()[0]
element1.getAttribute()
>>> 1
element2 = element1.getchildren()[0]
element2.getAttribute()
>>> 2
```